# If property doesn't exist get all records

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to build a query where a user selects multiple options, and we then filter the search based on the params. The data is a bit odd, where the property in the collection only exists for data added since a certain year. We have an option called null, if this is selected we want to add all records where this property does not exist.

At the moment, we build up an array of selected elements and use the mongodb in property to match all.

```
if (isset($params["value"])) {
  $match = preg_match_all('/value=(\w+)/', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $matches);
  $valueArray = array();

  foreach($matches[1] as $i => $item) {
    if(in_array(strtoupper($item), ["EA", "EA2", "WD1"])){
      array_push($valueArray, strtoupper($item));
    }

  }      
  
  if ($match > 0){
    $matchPipeline["value"] = ['$in'=> $valueArray];
  }
}
```

How would I update this to get all records that don't have the property of value if eitheir only 'Null' is selected, or is selected in addition to another value such as ea

Edit - Possible solution. I created a variable called $null if the NULL option is selected.

```
  if ($match > 0){
    if($null == true){
      $matchPipeline['$or'] = [
        ["value" => ['$in'=> $valueArray]],
        ["value" => ['$exists' => false]],
      ];
    } else {
      $matchPipeline["value"] = ['$in'=> $valueArray];}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would handle this by using [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or) in the match statement if `Null` is a selected option. The `$or` array would then contain the `$in` operator that you already have in addition to an [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists) operator. Here you would specify the field and `false` to return documents where the field does not exist.

Comment: I'm confused. How would I write this?

Comment: I've added a possible solution in my question. Is this ok?

Comment: It looks like it should work to me, but I'm not familiar with PHP. What happens when you run it?

Comment: It does work, i was just verifying if I was writing the correct code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i really appreciate it.